# Choosing Which latent variables to display and analyze

Tags: regression, pca, r-squared, partial-least-squares

Attached is a plot of the R-squared for each additional latent variable (LV) included in  a PLSR.[image]

When choosing which LVs to display on a biplot (and ultimately determining which factors best explain variance in the response variable) I am not sure which LVs to choose. Every source online always uses the first two (or more) LVs but in my case it looks like the addition of LV5 increases the R-squared of the regression more than LV2. Can I conclude that the loadings of X in LV5 describe the variation in y better than LV2? Or should I use LV1 and LV2 irrespective of the R-squared values.

I always assumed earlier components are decided as a way to maximize the correlations between X and y. If that is the case, then why am I seeing later components contribute more to the R-square?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you perform a principal component analysis and regress the principal components against $Y$, as your title and use of "PC" throughout the text would indicate, or did you perform a partial least squares regression as the first line of text would indicate?

Comment: @jbowman I performed a PLSR to correlate my X variables to a single Y variable. In the past, I have seen the term "PC" used in the context of PLSRs but I should have labeled the axes as Latent Variables to be more clear,